# How to emmit no data by Flowable for unit tests?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, rx-java

So, at start a little context about what I want to achive:

I have function in `DataManager` class named `getBusRoutesByQuery(query: String)` which returns `Flowable<List<Route>>`. That function search in local and remote storage for bus routes by given query. I'm using `zip` to combine two Flowables and merge them into one without duplicates. But for example when user will use app for the first time he won't have any data in local source so `zip` will not work. So I found a function `onErrorReturn` and I'm using it when there will be no data to return. `onErrorReturn` returns empty list instead of error, so remote source will `zip` with empty data. And now when I'm using in test `Flowble.empty()` to symulate situation where there is no data in local storage, test doesn't pass.

**Test assumptions**:

1. no data in local storage
2. data available in remote storage
3. `getBusRoutesByQuery(query: String)` is called from `DataManager`
4. data is retriven

Now how it looks in the code:

```
override fun getBusRoutesByQuery(query: String): Flowable<List<Route>> {
    val networkSourceWithSave: Flowable<List<Route>> = remoteBusDataManager
            .getBusRoutesByQuery(query)
            .doOnNext { localBusDataManager.insertBusRoutes(it) }
            .onErrorReturn { listOf() }
    val localSource: Flowable<List<Route>> = localBusDataManager
            .getBusRoutesByQuery(query)
            .onErrorReturn { listOf() }

    return Flowable.zip(localSource,
                        networkSourceWithSave,
                        BiFunction { local, remote -> mergeTwoListsWithoutDuplicates(local, remote) })
}
```

and the test:

```
@Test
fun getRoutesByQueryWhenLocalSourceIsNotAvailable() {
    `when`(localBusDataManager.getBusRoutesByQuery(QUERY)).thenReturn(Flowable.empty())
    `when`(remoteBusDataManager.getBusRoutesByQuery(QUERY)).thenReturn(Flowable.just(ROUTES))

    busDataManager.getBusRoutesByQuery(QUERY).subscribe(testSubscriber)

    testSubscriber.assertValue(ROUTES)
}
```

So tell me, what can I do with `zip`, when local storage data is not available and how can I test it. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is wrong. Zip will combine 1:1 on each stream, see documentation: http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html. Since one of your streams is empty there's nothing to zip and nothing will get pushed downstream.

Instead of zipping I'd suggest merge and distinct: `localSource.mergeWith(networkSourceWithSave).distinct()`